# Oauth2 custom implementation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, oauth, server

I am working on a site that will allow users to create an account. Then website developers will be able to integrate that authentication system into their site and allow users to login with my sites login credentials. I am wanting to do it similar to the way facebook connect,  Google,  twitter, Microsoft  works.

I have researched alot about this and discovered "Oauth2"  which I think is what I need.  But I'm not sure about how to use it anyhow.  I have downloaded two libraries of oauth2 (Php(server)  and Javascript(client)) but don't know where to start.

I simply want functionality where developers create a button which when clicked will send a request to my server and get the user's (who is currently logged in $_session) information from my server database and send it back to the third-party(the developers)  client page.

Problem is **Its not possible** to send session data from server.com to client.net using simple Ajax requests. So I thought oauth2 might be problem to my solution.

So what is it can anyone help me out? 
I have already read few of tutorials on oauth2 and nothing suits my needs.  So it would be great if someone can show a little working example.

Comment: If you don't understand oauth2 after reading "thousands" of tutorials you may need to take a few steps back and look into some basic web programming/security/HTTP protocol principles. Additionally I wouldn't recommend trying to implement your own version of oauth if you don't understand what oauth is and does. Sounds like a security disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: I didn't mean thousands I changed it.  But still I could get it working.  And security is something to be thought about later first I need to understand on how to use it properly